# RadioHead and Servo compile problems

Tags: arduino-uno

I am having this problem when trying to compile my sketch. I am using RF frequency modules to send data between devices and a servo motor to control the tilt of a ramp. I understand that both libraries use TIMER 1 but I am unsure how to change one of them to use TIMER 2 thanks.

```
Arduino: 1.8.7 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

libraries\Servo\avr\Servo.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `ServoCount':

(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_11'

libraries\RadioHead\RH_ASK.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.
Board at COM4 is not available

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force the RadioHead library to use Timer 2 instead. This can be done by enabling the define RH_ASK_ARDUINO_USE_TIMER2 near the top of RH_ASK.cpp.

More details about how to do this may be found in the RadioHead library documentation. Please see https://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/classRH__ASK.html.

Cheers!